# non standard - use '&' to create pointer to member

Tags: c++, function, object, boost

Forgive any ignorance, I'm new to c++.

Full error message:

`coog.cpp(74): error C3867: 'Manager::start_foo': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

I'm using boost command line and I'm trying to pass a object member function for the notifier. I've tried a variety of things from different posts on here and google but haven't had any luck. The error message is in the title.

Hopefully this will give you a idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Manager manager;

void coog::handle::start(std::vector<char const*>& args, Manager& m)
{
    po::options_description desc("Start allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("foo,f", po::value<std::vector<std::string>>()
            ->multitoken()->notifier(m.start_foo), "start foo(s)")
        ("example", "display an example of how to use each command")
        ("help", "display this message")
    ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(args.size(), args.data()).
        options(desc).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

}

coog::handle::start(foos, manager);
```

Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the entire error message?

Comment: `coog.cpp(74): error C3867: 'Manager::start_foo': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: Please use [edit] button to amend your question.

Comment: You simply cannot use `m.start_foo` unless immediately followed by an argument list, e.g. `m.start_foo("argument")`. To form a member function pointer you need to use `&Manager::start_foo`. The problem is that it won't work by itself because when it's time to call it, there's no `Manager` object around. You have to **bind** a `Manager` object to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a good quick explanation, that makes sense. Will do some more reading on the subject to get a better understanding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notifier` is function with this signature:

`typed_value * notifier(function1< void, const T & > f);`

You cannot just put here class-method, cause it's not suitable for this signature, you can use `boost::bind`, lambda, or something else, that will allow you to construct `function1` with signature specified above from your class-method.

Example with `bind`:

```
notifier(boost::bind(&Manager::start_foo, boost::ref(m), _1))
```

Example with lambda:

```
notifier([&m](const T& v) { return m.start_foo(v); })
```

That also depends on `start_foo` signature, you may need to bind more values.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Appreciate the post.

It is now working with the lambada. The parameters of the function are just a vector of strings. While I have you here could I please get a quick example of how to bind arguments? Would it be something like this? `notifier(boost::bind(&Manager::start_foo, boost::ref(m), std::vector<std::string> _1))`

Comment: @user3238415 just _1 should be enough. With lambda you should manually point type of parameter (i.e. `vector<std::string>`).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again.